# Traceback (most recent call last): , line 1, in <module> import unittest

Tags: python

No tengo idea de por qué me sale este error. Ya he revisado el código varias veces, pero no carga y sólo aparecen errores.

```
import unittest

def suma(num_1, num_2):
    return abs(num_1) + num_2

class CajaNegraTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_suma_dos_positivos(self):
        num_1 = 10
        num_2 = 5

        resultado = suma(num_1, num_2)

        self.assertEqual(resultado, 15)

    def test_suma_dos_negativos(self):
        num_1 = -10
        num_2 = -7

        resultado = suma(num_1, num_2)

        self.assertEqual(resultado, -17)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Creo que este es el error causante de que el resto no cargue, porque después empieza a llamar muchos archivos de los cuales no tengo idea ni de donde salieron. Ya mire la documentación de python y no entiendo :( estoy recién aprendiendo.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "c:/Users/Itzel/Desktop/python-course/caja_negra.py", line 1, in 
> import unittest

Comment: probablemente que el módulo unittest no lo tienes instalado, intenta con un `pip install unittest` en la ruta donde lo tienes instalado Python en la terminal y vuelve a ejecutar  el código

Comment: Hola considera traducir tu respuesta a idioma español o hacerlo en Stackoverflow Ingles.

Comment: Mil disculpas, voy a subir de nuevo la consulta, pensé que tenía que ser en inglés porque los demás tópicos me aparecían en ese idioma, lo siento

Comment: No es necesario que subas otra consulta, puedes editar esta pregunta y traducir la misma

Comment: Código ejecutado desde terminal con Python 3.8.3 y corre sin problemitas xDDD.

Comment: Guillermo, puse pip install unittest y me aparece el siguiente error:    ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement unittest (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for unittest
WARNING: You are using pip version 19.2.3, however version 20.1.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

Comment: unittest ya viene integrado con Python, creo.